# crystal report - Create report Not Equal to Column

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

i have two tables Students & attendance, they have a common field SID where they link

Students

SID |  Name  | Grade |  Age |

01  |  A1    | B1    |  8   |

02  |  A2    | B2    |  9   |

03  |  A3    | B1    |  8   |

04  |  A4    | B4    |  10  |

05  |  A5    | B1    |  8   |

06  |  A6    | B1    |  8   |

Attendance

AID  |  SID   | Present | Date     |

001  |  01    | YES     | 12-12-16 |

002  |  01    | YES     | 13-12-16 |

003  |  02    | YES     | 12-12-16 |

004  |  02    | YES     | 13-12-16 |

i want to create a report in crystal reports, which will give students which are absent, 
using the attendance table

I.E where attendance.SiD <> Student.SID

Comment: what is report structure?

Answer (score -1):

First create view using below query in database:

```
select * from Students where SID NOT IN (Select DISTINCT(SID) from Attendance);
```

- Create New form
- Drag N Drop Crested Report component on new form
- On right top side select view created from above query.
- Design form using lable and db field
- That's It.

OR IF YOU CAN NOT CREATE VIEW FOLLOW BELOW STEPS:

- Create New form
- Drag N Drop Crested Report component on new form
- select Student table for query
- Design form using lable and db field
- On Form load use below code

```html
SqlConnection cnn;
          string connectionString = null;
          string sql = null;
          connectionString = "connectring to sql server";
          cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
          cnn.Open();
          sql = "select * from Students where SID NOT IN (Select DISTINCT(SID) from Attendance)";
          SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
          DataSet ds = new DataSet();
          dscmd.Fill(ds, "data");
          objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
          crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
          crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Just manually assigned join table query.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, unfortunately i dont have access to create a view, i have to only use Crystal reports.